# Connectivity issue in Mongo5

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I have a project that uses Mongo 4.0 with Pymongo Motor and everything was working. Now that I'm trying to go to Mongo 5, I'm having connectivity issues.

Right at the beginning I see errors like this one:

```
"message": "Connectivity issue with MongoDB (retry 8), error: mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 645a2d11c0014433e98cef12, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongo', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')>]>"}
```

Looks like it's not finding the service, but nothing has changed from my side apart of upgrading the Mongo version.

I'm defining my Mongo with docker-compose as:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dta
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <password>
      MONGO_USERNAME: dta
      MONGO_PASSWORD: <password>
      MONGO_HOSTNAME: mongo
      BRANCH_NAME: ${BRANCH_NAME:-dev}
    command: --auth --oplogSize 32 --quiet --replSet -dta  --logpath /dev/stdout
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - ${MINIKUBE_REPO_PATH}/src/setup/mongo-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
volumes:
  mongodb:
```

Any ideas?